# Optimal Way to Achieve Traditional Loop Based Tasks in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am new to Scala and working on implementing an algorithm. In C#, this would have been a much easier task with necessary loops, but it is a bit confusing to implement with Scala functional programming semantics.

1. Assume I have to fill a spreadsheet (S) with N rows and M cols with values that I have in a one-dimensional list (L).
2. While filing an individual cell in the spreadsheet, there is a back and forth logic involved.

   2a. The system will walk through the items in L sequentially and will fill the same in next empty cell in sheet S

   2b. While filling the item value of the currently processed item from L in a cell, the system will check, can the current cell accept the item value. If yes, it will fill, and move on to the next item and follow Step 2a.  If not, it will see if it could fill the next item from L. Until it finds a value that could fit in, the system will continue to evaluate till it runs out of values and will leave it blank.

   2c. The system after filling the cell in Step 2b will move to the next cell. Now, it will first check whether any of the unprocessed values from the previous step (2b) could be accepted by the currently processed cell. If yes, it will fill the same and continue to do work with unprocessed values. If it cannot find an unprocessed value that could fit in, it will pull the next item from L based on the position of the pointer on Step 2b.

It would be great if I could get ideas of how-to structure this with Scala. As I mentioned earlier, in C# this would have been easy with foreach loops, but I am not sure what is the most optimal way to do this in a functional programming construct.

Comment: Probably a tail-recursive algorithm. Give it a try, over a list this should be pretty easy.

Comment: Scala also has foreach loops `for (elem <- collection)` even though they're just syntactic sugar for the foreach method

Comment: I would also suggest iterators (https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/iterators.html), which are handy for this sort of thing if you want to do it in a procedural way

Comment: All good suggestions, but I need to do a back and forth navigation as mentioned in Step 2c. That is the specific part I am very confused about.

Comment: @user: However, `for` comprehensions without `yield` / `foreach` is still not "functional". The very idea of a "loop" is diametrically opposed to the idea of functional programming. The fundamental idea of functional programming is "if you do the same thing, you get the same result". The fundamental idea of a loop is "you do the same thing over and over, but you get a different result at least once (namely, the loop exits)". A "functional loop" could only ever be a no-op or an infinite loop.

Comment: Note that there's nothing fundamentally wrong with using `foreach`, it just doesn't fit with the OP's question about doing it in a functional way.

Comment: @JörgWMittag My bad. I interpreted the question as "How do in Scala, which favors FP, what I did in C#?" instead of "How do what I did in C# in a functional way in Scala?"

Comment: Yes, I am trying to learn to do things the more functional way.

Answer (score 2):

You can remember that imperative:

```
for (init; condition; afterEach) {
  instructions
}
```

is just a syntactic sugar for:

```
init
while (condition) {
  instructions
  afterEach
}
```

(at least until you use `break` or `continue`). So if you are able to rewrite your for-loop code into while-loop code the translation is pretty straightforward.

If you are not interested in such solution you could do something like

```
val indices = for {
  i <- (0 until n).toStream // or .to(LazyList) if on 2.13
  j <- (0 until m).toStream // or .to(LazyList) if on 2.13
} yield i -> j

indices.foldLeft(allItemsToInsert) { case (itemsLeft, (i, j)) =>
  itemsLeft.find(item => /* predicate if item can be inserted at (i, j) */) match {
    case Some(item) =>
      // insert item to spreadsheet
      items diff List(1) // remove found element - use other data structure if you find this too costly
    case None =>
      items // nothing could be inserted, move on
  }
}
```

This would go through all indices one after another, and then try to find the first element which can be inserted. If it does it would insert it and take it off the list, if it cannot be inserted move on.

You can tweak the logic to e.g. partition on items that can be inserted if there could be more than one:

```
indices.foldLeft(allItemsToInsert) { case (itemsLeft, (i, j)) =>
  val (insertable, nonInsertable) = itemsLeft.partition(item => /* predicate if item can be inserted */)
  // insert insertable
  nonInsertable // pass non-insertable for the next indice
}
```

Alternatively you could also use tail recursion if you really need to go back and forth:

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec
def insertValues(items: List[Item], i: Int, j: Int): Unit = {
  if (items.nonEmpty) {
    // insert what you can into spreadsheet
    val itemsLeft = ... // items that you haven't inserted
    val newI, newJ = ...
    insertValues(itemsLeft, newI, newJ)
  }
}
```